# swift - execute both func even the first return true in or statement

Tags: swift

I'm trying to execute both functions but when the first return true, the second function is not executed.

```
func run() {
    if test1() || test2() {
        doSomething()
    }
}

func test1() -> Bool {
    print("test1")
    return true
}

func test2() -> Bool {
    print("test2")
    return false
}

func DoSomething() {
    print("something")
}

Getting Result ::
test1
something

Wanted Result ::
test1
test2
something
```

In **Android** we can use one **|** do it. But not in swift, if someone knows how to do.

Comment: not sure about java, but in kotlin `if (test1() | test2()) { }` doesn't compile, so which exactly android expression are you trying to repeat here?

Comment: *why* do you want test2 to run?

Comment: here is just an example, but in my project I try to validate textField are in correct format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swift `if` functions are called in a lazy way. For your `if` it's enough of `test1()` to return true to know the result of the expression so there's no need to call `test2()`, that's why it's skipped

If you need both methods to be called for some reason, you can try this:

```
if [test1(), test2()].contains(true) {
    doSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the logical or stops its evaluation if the first operand is true. So, if `test1` is true, `test2` will not be evaluated at all. It's advisable to store the result of both functions into variables if you want to execute both and perform the or on those stored values.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), and intentional. In principle it’s merely a performance optimization, but it has a semantic impact (which youre noticing here). In fact, it’s actually *required* by the specifications of many languages, including C, C++, Java, C++, etc.

The entire premise here is quite fishy. To have noticed that test2 doesn’t run, means that test2 has a side effect (in your example, printing a message). This is a violation of the principle of [Command/Query separation](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html). This is bad design, akin to having a ruler that drills the material it measures.

If you provide more detail as to what test1 and test2 actually do, we can probably suggest a better approach.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is I have a form with textFields and when the user click on sending button, it's check if the all fields so test1 and test2 are checking if the field is not empty and have the correct format if not : trigger some error and the doSomething() is a return to cancel the sending.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, then test1 = “field isn’t empty” and test2 = “field has correct format”. Why do you want to check if the format is right/wrong in a field that’s empty? You already know the field has an invalid value.

Comment: test1 is check one textfield and test2 for another textfield, like test1 is for the email input and test2 is for phone input

Comment: @toto12344 Okay, sure. Same question applies: why do you want to check that the phone is valid if you already know that the email is invalid?

Comment: print error of each invalid input instead of just the first error, when a user fill a form it's annoying when the click on send find a error, the user change it and click again on send and find another error and so on

Comment: So the side effect of checking if a field is valid is to somehow show the user an error if it’s valid. Do you see how that goes against command/query separation?

Comment: ?? it's show the error only on the field that are invalid

Comment: @toto12344 I don't think you understood my comments.

Comment: it does not show error for the field that are valid but it does cancel the sending of the form that are of the effect that I wanted.

Comment: @toto12344 That's still has the same kind of violation. Did you read https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html ?

Comment: I did, he's talking about method that set something and return nothing, and getting method

Comment: @toto12344 Specifically yes, but the more general principle is about side effects in general. "but it does cancel the sending of the form" is one such side effect.